Creating a console for the new tabbed Notepad
I know it's not what ConEmu was designed for, but I like to have everything together when I'm working on a project... I'm able to ATTACH the New Tabbed Notepad to a ConEmu console by using the "Alternative mode" and it works ok.
Two things:

It leaves a Terminal task running in my taskbar - I'd like it to close automatically.
How can I create a permanent task for this?

